# Importing text file into Excel gets caught on second run of code

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am trying to get powerpoint to open find the newest text file in a folder, open the text file with excel, format the text file, then save the file as an xlsx. Then that final document will be updated in the powerpoint presentation.

The problem I have is the code will run once and does as it is supposed to do. Then on the next iteration powerpoint crashes. It appears the code keeps a tie to excel and I can't figure out how to sever it at the codes conclusion. Any ideas?

```
Sub ImportFormatIN3()


    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim TargetFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim LatestFile As String
    Dim latestDate As Date
    Dim LMD As Date

    'Defined path to reports
    MyPath = "R:\filelocation\"
    TargetFolder = "C:\midfilelocation\FinalIN3.txt"

    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.txt")
    If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
      Exit Sub
    End If

    'Find the newest file in the mypath
    Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
        LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)
        If LMD > latestDate Then
            LatestFile = MyFile
            latestDate = LMD
        End If
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    FileCopy MyPath & LatestFile, TargetFolder

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlApp.Visible = True


    'On Error Resume Next
    With xlApp.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;midfilelocation\FinalIN3.txt", Destination:=Range("A1"))

        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(4, 10, 10, 9, 18, 15, 23, 32, 12, 5, 7, 13, 9, 6)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Rows("1:9").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("M:M,N:N").Select
    Range("N1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("F20").Select


     Columns("D").EntireColumn.Delete
     Columns("H").EntireColumn.Delete
     Columns("I").EntireColumn.Delete
     Columns("G").EntireColumn.Delete
     Columns("C").EntireColumn.Delete
     Columns("A").EntireColumn.Delete


     Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 25
     Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 25
     Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 30
     Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 60
     Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 15


     Range("A1:E1").EntireRow.Insert
     Range("A1:E1").Merge
     Range("A:E").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
     Range("A:E").Font.Size = 15
     Range("A1").Font.Size = 30
     Range("A1").Value = "IN3 Dispatch as of " & latestDate


    Dim KillConnects As Long
    With ActiveWorkbook
        For KillConnects = .Connections.Count To 1 Step -1
            .Connections(KillConnects).Delete
        Next KillConnects
    End With

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\finalfilelocation\FinalIN3Document.xlsx", AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    xlApp.Workbooks.Close

 End Sub
```

Comment: All of your Excel objects need to be fully qualified.   PowerPoint knows nothing of Excel `Range`, `Column` etc. I would also remove reliance on `ActiveSheet`, `Select`, `Selection` etc and set variables to the required objects. Use `xlApp.Quit` to close the created instance of Excel

Comment: You need to clear out the Excel variable by setting it to nothing after it has been closed.  `Set xlApp = Nothing`. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I believe the line "With xlApp.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;midfilelocation\FinalIN3.txt", Destination:=Range("A1"))'code' is the issue.                                         I read the easiest way to sort a non-deliminated text file into excel is with a macro so that is what I did.  Is there a better way to handle this?  Sorry I can't figure out how to make the code tag work in the comments...

Comment: The code tag in the comments is a single ` character followed by a closing ` character with no spaces at the end ex: ` `codehere` `

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear out the Excel variable by setting it to nothing after it has been closed. Also, add the `xlApp.DisplayAlerts` = False line.

after

```
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\finalfilelocation\FinalIN3Document.xlsx", 
       AccessMode:=xlExclusive, 
       ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges

    xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close

    xlApp.Workbooks.Close

    xlApp.Quit
```

put the following:

```
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

That should fix the problem.

Comment: You would probably want to close Excel first though, otherwise the loop will open multiple instances as it goes along. Use `xlApp.Quit` before setting to `Nothing`

Comment: Again, I thank you all for the answers.  I have tried just about everything I can think of and had no luck.  Every time I run the code a second time I get the error: Run-time error 1004 Method Range of object_Global failed.  It works fantastic the first run-through though!

Comment: Check out the update. I modified some things and added `xlApp.DisplayAlerts =  False`

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding xlAPP in front of most of the code (see below).  Thanks again for all of your help on this everyone.  Is there something I need to do to mark this as solved?

```
With xlApp.ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:filepath\begin.txt", Destination:=xlApp.Cells(1, 1))

        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlFixedWidth
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileFixedColumnWidths = Array(4, 10, 10, 9, 18, 15, 23, 32, 12, 5, 7, 13, 9, 6)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    xlApp.Rows("1:9").Select
    xlApp.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    xlApp.Columns("A:A").Select
    xlApp.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    xlApp.Rows("2:2").Select
    xlApp.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    xlApp.Range("M:M,N:N").Select
    xlApp.Range("N1").Activate
    xlApp.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    xlApp.Columns("K:K").Select
    xlApp.Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    xlApp.Range("F20").Select


     xlApp.Columns("D").EntireColumn.Delete
     xlApp.Columns("H").EntireColumn.Delete
     xlApp.Columns("I").EntireColumn.Delete
     xlApp.Columns("G").EntireColumn.Delete
     xlApp.Columns("C").EntireColumn.Delete
     xlApp.Columns("A").EntireColumn.Delete


     xlApp.Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 25
     xlApp.Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 25
     xlApp.Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 30
     xlApp.Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 60
     xlApp.Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 15


     xlApp.Range("A1:E1").EntireRow.Insert
     xlApp.Range("A1:E1").Merge
     xlApp.Range("A:E").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
     xlApp.Range("A:E").Font.Size = 15
     xlApp.Range("A1").Font.Size = 30
     xlApp.Range("A1").Value = "IN3 Dispatch as of " & latestDate


    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\filepath\end.xlsx", AccessMode:=xlExclusive, ConflictResolution:=Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlLocalSessionChanges

    xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close

    xlApp.Workbooks.Close


   xlApp.Quit
   Excel.Application.Quit
```